# Github - fork my repository to create new repositories without creating new accounts

Tags: git, github, git-fork

I have a repository called "coreengine", this repository has all the code that is common in all my other repositories. So whenever i have to create a new project i just want to fork this coreengine and then start working on the new repository.

Now whenever i update the coreengine i want to be able to pull all the changes to all my forked repositories.

**Problem:** I have done this before in bitbucket, where i was able to create multiple forks with a single account. But in github i am only allowed to create a single fork with a single account.

How can i achieve multiple forks of a single repository with the same account? I am sure there will be a solution for this.

Comment: What about a "poor mans fork": clone your "base" repository and then do `git remote remove origin && git remote add origin ${YOU_NEW_PROJECT_ON_GITHUB} && git add remote base ${THE_ORIGILAL_CLONE_URI}` then you can get changes from your base repository by `git pull base`

Comment: Honestly, I don't think this is the correct use case for a fork.  I would recommend cloning the template repo, wiping .git, and pushing up what's there as an initial import for a new application.

Comment: @MaxFriederichs you are correct and i understand that this is not the main reason why forks are used and maybe this is the reason that github only allows 1 fork per account. But from my past experience this is quite a good solution for problem that didn't have a viable solution before.